# Enable ARM errata in inline assembly

Tags: c, assembly, arm, imx6

I'm trying to learn `asm` by enabling workarounds for errata in a driver. That should be possible because kernel code is executed in the privileged world. The (minimalistic) code looks as follows.

```c
unsigned int cp15c15 = 0, result = 0;
__asm__ volatile("mrc p15, 0, %0, c15, c0, 1" : "=r" (cp15c15));
cp15c15 |= (1<<22); /* Errata 845369 */
__asm__ volatile("mcr p15, 0, %0, c15, c0, 1" : "+r" (cp15c15));
```

This seems to be working, but when I read the register multiple times, I sometimes get a value without bit 22 enabled. (For example `0x000001` instead of `0x400001`).

```
char buf[10];
__asm__ volatile("mrc p15, 0, %0, c15, c0, 1" : "=r" (cp15c15));
sprintf(buf, "0x%.8x", cp15c15);
copy_to_user(buffer, buf, 10);
```

I think I'm doing something wrong in the `asm` call. If someone can give me insight in why this only works 10% of the time, I really would appreciate it. (Asm is kind of cool).

EDIT:
The assembly code from the original NXP errata description:

```
MRC p15,0,rt,c15,c0,1
ORR rt,rt,#0x00400000
MCR p15,0,rt,c15,c0,1
```

EDIT 2:
If I enable this in ./linux/arch/arm/mm/proc-v7.S, the bit remains set when I read it from my driver. However if I disable it, it seems that bit switches off and on irregularly. It seems to corroborate to when the bit is set.

Comment: You don't reference `%1` in your 2nd asm template.  Are you assuming that it's going to pick the same register for `"r" (cp15c15)` as for `"=r"(result)`?  Because that's not guaranteed.  Use a matching constraint like `"0"(cp15c15)`, or use a single `"+r" (cp15c15)` read/write operand.

Comment: BTW, I assume this is actually enabling a *workaround* or mitigation for an erratum.  An erratum is a hardware design bug, you don't want to *enable* bugs.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @PeterCordes. `+r` is much cleaner than I had, but it doesn't fix the problem (I think I made this error due to trying to get it work). Also, indeed, I'm not trying to introduce more errors :-)

Comment: Ok, now your asm is sane and should reliably do what it's trying to do.  Perhaps the erratum itself explains why the bit reads variably if it wasn't set manually, IDK.  It's certainly plausible that writing it as `1` has a side-effect that causes the behaviour to change.

Comment: I think that it has something to do with writing to it once the kernel is fully started. The asm in `proc-v4.S` is "start up" code, so it could be that the chip is already doing stuff with this register and that's why it's toggling.

Comment: Are you running this on all cpus?

Comment: @TimothyBaldwin what do you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the computer has multiple processor cores (like some i.MX 6 chips) then unless you make arrangements to run this all processor cores, the processor it runs on will be at the whim of the Linux scheduler.

Therefore might set the register on one CPU, then if the check is run on the that CPU the modification will show, but if the check is run on a different CPU the original value will be read.

Comment: The processor indeed has multiple cores. I would like to verify if I can run this on all cores before accepting your answer, but I think you've made a very good argument. Thanks.